# In Android, I have a view that disappears from screen if the screen height isn't big enough

Tags: android, layout, view

I have a vertical layout with a heading, a listView, and a bottom bar with a couple of buttons. Everything works fine if the screen is tall enought to fit all the data, but as soon as there is too much data in the listView to fit on the screen, the bottom toolbar with the uttons disappears. And the same thing happens if I rotate the phone from portrait to landscape (because the data fits on the portrait screen and not on the landscape one). Here's the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup_list" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?popupBgStyle" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/popup_lbl"       
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        style="?popupHeaderStyle" />

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        style="?insideBgStyle" >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/chk_list_msg" 
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

        <ListView android:id="@+id/chk_list_view" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_margin="0dip"
        android:padding="0dip"
        style="?popupFooterStyle" >

        <Button android:id="@+id/btn_popup"  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            style="?popupBtnStyle" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried setting the layout_weight=1 to the bottom toolbar, and layout_weight=0 to the layout with the listView, but that doesn't help. Any suggestions?

Comment: why not put it in a scrollview?

Comment: I can see the visibility of footer is set as gone. can you try with relative layout instead of linear layout?

Comment: the visibility is toggled at runtime, and I've removed it from the OP. And yes, RelativeLayout has the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I have checked this and for testing purpose. I modified some values 
just have a try on this and modify according to your need

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/popup_list"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/popup_lbl"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:text="dummy"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="6"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chk_list_msg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dummy"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/chk_list_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="6"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="0dip" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_popup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="dummy"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

hope it will help you

Comment: in your example, weightsum=10, but the sum of the 3 weights is 14 (2 + 6 + 6). Did you do tha ton purpose?

Comment: ohk...for the bottom linearlayout take that one to be 2.

Comment: i have tested it ...my side it is ok...i have captured this layout graphical view here....i didn't know how to post here thats why i am waiting..

Comment: your code is bad -- you set the ListView height to "380dp", but it needs to be wrap_content

Comment: I have edit source code of GVSharma. That will help you to find the answer with the help of weight sum... Try that...

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ListView`s height to 0dp and set the weight to 1. This way it will stretch all the way but keep the top and bottom in screen.

Comment: Did you mean so say ListView, or the middle layout that holds the ListView?

Comment: You are right, I mean the middle layout that contains the `ListView`. Set the `ListView`s height to `match_parent`.